# How to set an question image to ImageView from Firebase in QuizApp

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, imageview

I am working on a quiz app basically. In my app there are many questions getting datas from Firebase Database with those areas (question, optionA,optionB,optionC,optionD and correctANS) but I want to improve my project. I want to add image questions instead of text questions. For this I added an area(urlImage) to my database on Firebase. Normally I can get data from Firebase except urlImage but I didn't see Image in ImageView in my app. What should i do? Please someone help me?

those are my QuestionsActivity codes:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);
        Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        question=findViewById(R.id.question);
        urlImage=findViewById(R.id.urlImage);
        noIndicator=findViewById(R.id.no_indicator);
        bookmarkBtn=findViewById(R.id.bookmark_btn);
        optionsContainer=findViewById(R.id.option_container);
        shareBtn=findViewById(R.id.share_btn);
        nextBtn=findViewById(R.id.next_btn);

        preferences=getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor=preferences.edit();
        gson=new Gson();

        getBookmarks();
        bookmarkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (modelMatch()){
                    bookmarkslist.remove(matchedQuestionPosition);
                    bookmarkBtn.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.bookmark_border));
                }else{
                    bookmarkslist.add(list.get(position));
                    bookmarkBtn.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.bookmark));
                }
            }
        });


        setId=getIntent().getStringExtra("setId");

        loadingDialog=new Dialog(this);
        loadingDialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading);
        loadingDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_corner2));
        loadingDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);

        list=new ArrayList<>();
        loadingDialog.show();
        myRef.child("SETS").child(setId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String id=dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                    String question= dataSnapshot1.child("question").getValue().toString();
                    String a= dataSnapshot1.child("optionA").getValue().toString();
                    String b= dataSnapshot1.child("optionB").getValue().toString();
                    String c= dataSnapshot1.child("optionC").getValue().toString();
                    String d= dataSnapshot1.child("optionD").getValue().toString();
                    String correctANS= dataSnapshot1.child("correctANS").getValue().toString();
                    String urlImage= dataSnapshot1.child("urlImage").getValue().toString();

                    list.add(new QuestionModel(id,question,a,b,c,d,correctANS,urlImage,setId));

                }
                if (list.size() > 0){
                    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
                        optionsContainer.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                checkhanswer(((Button)view));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    playAnim(question,0,list.get(position).getQuestion());
                    
                    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            nextBtn.setEnabled(false);
                            nextBtn.setAlpha(0.7f);
                            enableOption(true);
                            position++;
                            if (position==list.size()){
                                Intent scoreIntent=new Intent(QuestionsActivity.this,ScoreActivity.class);
                                scoreIntent.putExtra("score",score);
                                scoreIntent.putExtra("total",list.size());
                                startActivity(scoreIntent);
                                finish();
                                return;
                            }
                            count=0;
                            playAnim(question,0,list.get(position).getQuestion());
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(QuestionsActivity.this, "There isn't any question.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(QuestionsActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });
//        playAnim(question,0,list.get(position).getQuestion());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        storeBookmarks();
    }

    private void playAnim(final View view, final int value, final String data){
//        for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
//            optionsContainer.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundTintList(null);
//        }
        view.animate().alpha(value).scaleX(value).scaleY(value).setDuration(500).setStartDelay(100)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                if (value == 0 && count<4){
                    String option="";
                    if (count==0){
                        option=list.get(position).getA();
                    }
                    else if(count==1){
                        option=list.get(position).getB();
                    }
                    else if(count==2){
                        option=list.get(position).getC();
                    }
                    else if(count==3){
                        option=list.get(position).getD();
                    }
                    playAnim(optionsContainer.getChildAt(count),0,option);

                    count++;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                ((TextView)view).setText(data);

                if (value==0){
                    try {
                        ((TextView)view).setText(data);
                        noIndicator.setText(position+1+"/"+list.size());
                        if (modelMatch()){

                            bookmarkBtn.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.bookmark));
                        }else{

                            bookmarkBtn.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.bookmark_border));
                        }
                    }catch (ClassCastException e){
                        ((Button)view).setText(data);
                    }
                    view.setTag(data);
                    playAnim(view,1,data);
//                    playAnim(urlResim,0,list.get(position).getUrlResim());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

            }
        });

    }
```

those are my QuestionModel codes:

```
public class QuestionModel {
    private String id,question,A,B,C,D,answer,set,urlImage;

    public QuestionModel(String id, String question, String a, String b, String c, String d, String answer,
                         String set,String urlImage) {
        this.id = id;
        this.question = question;
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
        D = d;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.set = set;
        this.urlImage=urlImage;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return A;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        A = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return B;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        B = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return C;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        C = c;
    }

    public String getD() {
        return D;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        D = d;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getSet() {
        return set;
    }

    public void setSet(String set) {
        this.set = set;
    }

    public String getUrlImage() {
        return urlImage;
    }

    public void setUrlImage(String urlResim) {
        this.urlImage = urlImage;
    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I haven't seen image in the Imageview. Questions and options appear, but pictures do not appear. how to get and show images from firebase to Imageview? The application does not give an error, but the images do not appear.

Comment: Here's an image link to (https://ibb.co/0fvXf2Y)

Comment: When you get the data, does `urlImage` hold a valid URL?

Comment: yes it does. I understand this from here, when I pull the image to a textview instead of an imageview, the url appears. but when I type url instead of imageview it doesn't show up.

Comment: Have you tried to use Glide?

Comment: when I set to optionA I can see to database image URL. but when I set to yellow area in the ImageView I can't seen. You can see in this image. Here's an image link to (https://ibb.co/P67ZW73)

Comment: @AlexMamo I haven't tried to use Glide.

Comment: Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: @AlexMamo I haven't use glide before. I am sorry for this. Where to I must write glide codes in my project. Can you tell me?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) out.